# Structural equation modeling in R -- are there any good books or tutorials?

Tags: r

Are there any good resources for learning how to construct structural equation models in R?  A friend asked for help transitioning from SPSS' Amos for structural equation modeling to R.  He has limited R skills and I have limited SEM knowledge.  Are there any books/book chapters/etc along the lines of the [Use R!](http://www.springer.com/series/6991) series that cover SEM packages for R?

Comment: See one (or perhaps more) of the [task views](http://cran.at.r-project.org/web/views/SocialSciences.html) on CRAN.

Comment: http://jarrettbyrnes.info/ubc_sem/

Comment: http://www.r-bloggers.com/free-video-courses-on-r-structural-equation-modelling-causal-inference-and-regression-from-uni-jena/

Answer (score 5):

A quick google search reveals:

- [Structural Equation Modeling in R](http://personality-project.org/r/r.sem.html)
- [Structural Equation Models - 
  Appendix to An R and S-PLUS Companion to Applied Regression](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Fox-Companion/appendix-sems.pdf)
- [R packages for Structural Equation Model](http://pairach.com/2011/08/13/r-packages-for-structural-equation-model/)

The following packages on CRAN may be helpful:

- [`sem` (structural equation modelling)](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sem/index.html) that contains links to the [package author's website](http://socserv.socsci.mcmaster.ca/jfox/)
- [`lavaan` (latent variable analyis)](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lavaan/index.html)

Comment: Take a look at the `lavaan` package too.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @BenBolker, I've added `lavaan` and a link to CRAN

Comment: I think this is a good tutorial too: http://socserv.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Misc/sem/SEM-paper.pdf

Comment: The ```OpenMx``` package can also be used for structural equation modelling

Answer (score 3):

With reference to Structural Equation Modelling, the theory is the hard part. If your friend has that, then he should be OK.

I personally like OpenMx (even though its not completely open source), as it is fast, has parallel facilities and can handle an extremely wide variety of models though coding the algebra by hand.

The user guide is extremely good: http://openmx.psyc.virginia.edu/documentation

One issue with it is the use of Graphviz for diagrams, which could cause problems if you are running it on Windows. Lavaan and sem are also quite good, but the optimisers tend to fail on badly behaved matrcies where OpenMx can handle it. Whether you regard that as a good or bad thing is a matter of preference.